# Weird flashing when scrolling tex coords of procedurally generated texture

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

The procedurally generated texture appears fine, until I start trying to scroll the texture coords utilizing GL_REPEAT. If I scroll just a normal image that I've uploaded, then it is scrolling fine. But the procedural one does this weird, periodic flashing effect. I'm trying to generate a starfield, so it's just white dots on a transparent background, and with this problem the stars are fading to almost black then back to white and so on. Also, if i generate a substantial number of stars, there are a few that don't exhibit this behavior, but seem normal.

here i just setup the texture for opengl and establish the pixels array.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex_id);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
GLubyte *pixels=new GLubyte[(screen_width)*(screen_height)*4];
```

here i setup my random number generators and i fill in the pixel data for the number of stars i want.

```
irngX=new IRNG(0,screen_width-1);
irngY=new IRNG(0,screen_height-1);
for (int i=0; i<count; ++i){
        int x=irngX->get();
        int y=irngY->get();
        int pos=(y*screen_width*4)+(x*4);
        pixels[pos++]=(GLubyte)255;
        pixels[pos++]=(GLubyte)255;
        pixels[pos++]=(GLubyte)255;
        pixels[pos++]=(GLubyte)255;
}
```

here i upload the pixels to opengl...the pixel store function seems to have no effect on anything, unlike desktop opengl, nor do i understand its usage anyways. ive tried it on and off.

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1); // ?? 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,screen_width,screen_height,0,
             GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4);
```

here's my tex coord scroller:

```
tex_scroller+=0.001f;
glUniform1f(tex_scroller_loc,tex_scroller);
```

and in the shader:

```
vtex.t+=tex_scroller;
```

i hope that's all the relevant code, and that i've made my problem understandable. please let me know if you need a better description.
p.s. i apolozie if my code is not formatted properly. i tried.

Comment: It might be precision related. Make sure your UV coordinates and `tex_scroller` uniform are highp in your vertex and fragment shaders. Also, I'd recommend adding `if (tex_scroller > 1.0f) tex_scroller -= 1.0f;` after the `tex_scroller+=0.001f;` line otherwise precision will gradually deteriorate given enough time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably about texture sampling. Your stars are just a single texel in size, and when you're scrolling, the grid of screen pixels is no longer aligned perfectly with the grid of texels, so texture filtering is occuring (`GL_LINEAR`) which affects the brightness. This is particularly a problem because your transparent texels are presumably black. Some suggestions:

- Try changing 'GL_LINEAR' to 'GL_NEAREST' in your code above. This should fix any fading, but might replace it with an on/off flickering.
- Try making the transparent texels white, that will improve things.
- Try changing `tex_scroller+=0.001f;` to `tex_scroller+=1.0f/screen_width;` to see if you can keep the texel grid and pixel grid aligned
- Try changing your stars to be multiple texels in size instead of single texel.

Comment: that was the issue! changing GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST fixed it. subtle! thanks so much, i dont think i could have figured that one out. shows how little i understand about texturing. would you still recommend the other changes? specifically the part about making the transparent texels white.